# Is a varying a pixel?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I am writing a Fragment shader for an Open GL ES application, and Im trying to clarify the difference between a Pixel and a Varying?

Answer (score 2):

A `varying` type in OpenGL ES contains an optional, user-defined output from the vertex shader to the fragment shader (e.g. a surface normal if using per-pixel lighting). It is used to calculate the final fragment color (`gl_FragColor`) within the fragment shader. While a final color can be output from the vertex shader (e.g. if using per-vertex lighting) as a `varying` type, this is not the norm and depends on your desired shader behaviour.

A `pixel` is simply the smallest measured unit of an image or screen. The OpenGL ES pipeline produces `fragments` (raw data) which are then converted (or not) to pixels, depending on their visibility, depth, stencil, colour, etc.